# Open all dbf files in a folder and save them as excel in another folder

Tags: vba

I have a folder "test" containing several dbf files. I would like vba to open them in excel file and save them (in excel format) in another folder keeping the same dbf file names.

I found this code on the net and am trying to use this code for my needs but it won't work. Error message:

> "sub of function not defined"

...please look into it.

```
Sub test()

Dim YourDirectory As String
Dim YourFileType As String
Dim LoadDirFileList As Variant
Dim ActiveFile As String
Dim FileCounter As Integer
Dim NewWb As Workbook

YourDirectory = "c:\Users\navin\Desktop\test\"
YourFileType = "dbf"

LoadDirFileList = GetFileList(YourDirectory)
If IsArray(LoadDirFileList) = False Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
Else
    ' Loop around each file in your directory
    For FileCounter = LBound(LoadDirFileList) To UBound(LoadDirFileList)
        ActiveFile = LoadDirFileList(FileCounter)
        Debug.Print ActiveFile
        If Right(ActiveFile, 3) = YourFileType Then
            Set NewWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(YourDirectory & ActiveFile)
            Call YourMacro(NewWb)
            NewWb.SaveAs YourDirectory & Left(ActiveFile, Len(ActiveFile) - 4) & ".xlsx"
            NewWb.Saved = True
            NewWb.Close
            Set NewWb = Nothing
        End If
    Next FileCounter
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing the functions `GetFileList` and `YourMacro`. A quick search brought me to this website (I think you copied it from there). http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/printthread.php?t=56393

There are the missing functions. Copy those two also in your modul to make it run (I tested it with pdf-Files):

```
Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant
' Author : Carl Mackinder (From JWalk)
' Last Update : 25/05/06
' Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec
'  If no matching files are found, it returns False

Dim FileArray() As Variant
Dim FileCount As Integer
Dim FileName As String

On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

FileCount = 0
FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

'  Loop until no more matching files are found
Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
        FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
        FileName = Dir()
Loop
    GetFileList = FileArray
Exit Function

NoFilesFound:
    GetFileList = False
End Function

Sub YourMacro(Wb As Workbook)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Wb.Worksheets(1)
ws.Range("A6").Value = "=((+A2*$CN2)+(A3*$CN3)+(A4*$CN4)+(A5*$CN5))/SUM($CN2:$CN5)"
ws.Range("A6").Copy ws.Range("B6:CM6")
ws.Range("CO6").Value = "=CO2"
End Sub
```

To save files in a different directory:

```
Dim SaveDirectory As String
SaveDirectory = "c:\Users\navin\Desktop\test\converted to excel"
```

Replace this line

```
NewWb.SaveAs YourDirectory & Left(ActiveFile, Len(ActiveFile) - 4) & ".xlsx"
```

with this

```
 NewWb.SaveAs SaveDirectory & Left(ActiveFile, Len(ActiveFile) - 4) & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: @katz...yes indeed i copied it from there....are those necessary as well?? whats the purpose of the below part??

Comment: @Navin yes the functions are necessary for the code, just try it

Comment: @katz..Yes it did work...One last thing please...which part do I have to change so as to save the excel files in a different folder (for e.g in c:\Users\navin\Desktop\test\converted to excel)

Comment: @Navin I updated my answer. Pls try it and mark my answer as your solution. thanks

Comment: hi katz...sorry but how do i  mark your answer as my solution??